# Auto alignment of nested if

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, code-formatting

One of the neat features of visual studio is the auto alignment. But there's one thing that I don't understand about this.

When using nested statements as follows (I'll illustrate with `if` statements, I use this construction usually with `for` statements):

```
//pseudo code
if(condition a)
    if(condition b){
    do something;
    do something else;
    }
```

The visual studio auto alignment feature will align as shown above. However, I would expect that according to common alignment etiquettes the code 'should' be like this:

```
//pseudo code
if(condition a)
    if(condition b){
        do something;
        do something else;
    }
```

The behaviour gets more pronounced when using a third or fourth layer of nesting:

```
if(condition a)
    if(condition b)
         if(condition c){
    do something;
    do something else;
         }
```

Given that visual studio is a very matured IDE this probably is intended behaviour. But I've never seen it anywhere else. Is this some convention I'm not aware of and can I get away with code like this? Or should I manually re-indent, or add brackets for every nesting layer?

Comment: Visual Studio is trying to tell you that it finds your lack of brackets disturbing. Presumably it also uses them to calculate the indent level.

Comment: @user657267 Do you think three layers of {} would improve readability here?

Comment: That is an odd bug - I hadn't noticed it as we have guidelines that say always use braces when the inner statement is more than one line. Note: I am not sure how you expect your last example to be indented - you have a new block in both cases.

Comment: @TheDark Yes you are right, the last example isn't good. I've removed it, it shows up only when using a new line for the brackets. The brackets will change indent, but the code won't. About the braces when the inner statement is more than one line, does that hold true for this example? I find the behaviour quite clear as it is.

Comment: Yes, our rule is "braces when more than one *line*" rather than *statement*. In this case your outer if statement has 4 lines in its inner statement, even it is is just one statement. I'm not saying its the best rule ever (braces everywhere is another option), but it works for us.

Comment: @TheDark Okay, maybe I should just start doing that too. After all this isn't worth wasting too much time over:)

Comment: No, but it is interesting. Note: I tried the same thing in WebStorm and it indented as you would expect.

Comment: I tried it in my VS2013 and it also indented as you expected, it must have something to do with some formatting properties...

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf Yeah I've tried several editors, so far all of them behave that way but visual studio.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with VS2013. I've installed Visual Assist which may be the reason for this. Anyway, if DeepBackDwarf is right maybe it helps to rename (i.e. backup and delete) the .suo file in the solution folder.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi That's interesting. I do have visual assist installed. But I disabled it, when checking this behaviour. It might still be the reason though. Removing the suo file doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: @TheDark Do you have visual assist installed if I may ask:)?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the checkbox Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting > General > "Automatically format braces when they are automatically completed", when unchecked it produces a behavior close to the one you describe

Comment: @DeepBlackDwarf That seems to match with the behaviour I described before (and I triggered through `Ctrl` + `k`)

Comment: I have that bug too with vs2010.

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov I'm not sure it's a bug actually

Comment: How come? Try this: if (a) \n if(b) \n { \n } \n c; Here c will be indented incorrectly.

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov Are you sure? c is not inside of any if clause here, so to me it seems right;)

Comment: On my setup (again it's vs2010, different from OP), c is indented once using msvc's auto-indent. I've seen this kind of bug around nested ifs, when brackets are not explicitly used on each level.

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov Well that would be quite a serious error. I don't currently have vs2010 on hand to check:(. What happens to any lines after `c`?

Comment: The wrong indentation perpetuates. You can guess that I now use brackets after every single if-clause.

Comment: @BoykoPerfanov Yes that's a serious bug. You can end up with incredibly indented lines on large documents. Is it okay if I add this to the question after checking for myself?

Comment: That would be awesome @laurisvr !

Comment: @laurisvr No, I don't have visual assist installed. I might go have a look at it though.